# css scroll/touch slide view - how to use -ms-scroll-snap or the like?

Tags: html, css, touch

I discovered the new css controlling scrolling and snapping on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466066.aspx

I wonder if there's a tutorial or sample out there explaining how this works and to use those css-attributes.

I'm working on a (angularjs based) calendar and I wonder if it's possible to extend it using css to support touch panning trough the months (like win8 calendar navigating with the fingers).

http://jsfiddle.net/johnnayweiler/FyrtQ/

How to use like -ms-scroll-snap to make the view go with the finger, then snap to the next page? What js events would be recommended to know when the scroll amount reached this snap point(to load the next month).

Also of course, is there something similar in other browsers(this doesnt seem to be a standarts feature)? Probably using javascript, are there some simple solutions for handling momentum and snap?

Thanks for your ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres now an official sample ;)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/Scrolling-panning-and-6834aaf9/sourcecode?fileId=68336&pathId=380363024